# In "$\,f_w(x) = \sum_{i}\frac{1}{2}\|wx_i + c - Y\|_2^2\,$", what do the stacked "$2$"s at the end mean?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors, absolute-value, index-notation

I got an equation and for me it is not clear for what the last stacked 2's is for?

$$f_w(x) = \sum_{i}\frac{1}{2}\|wx_i + c - Y\|_2^2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think more context is needed to answer your question. Where did you get this equation from? You should in general include as much relevant background information as you can when you ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

That’s the square of the two-norm (aka the Euclidean norm).

Answer (score 0):

The subscript is relative to the norm being used. The "2" stands for the euclidean norm. The superscript is a power.
$$
\|X\|_2^2 = \left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right)^{1/2}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2
$$

Other examples of norms could be

$$
\|X\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|, \quad \|X\|_{\infty}= \max_{i=1,\cdots, n}|X_i|.
$$